# Delete the duplicate rows from table having foreign key of another table?

Tags: sql, database, duplicates, foreign-keys, subquery

I am having two tables `employee` and `departments`.
employee table having

```
ID , name ,  salary, dep_ID
1  | john |  2300  | 1
2  | smith|  1500  | 2
3  | john |  2300  | 1
```

here the `dep_id` is a `foreign key`

now department

```
id, name
1 | COMPUTER SCIENCE
2 | MATHEMATICS
```

Now what I want to do is "delete all the duplicate row from the employee table "

Comment: MySQL or oracle? Which database are you using?

Comment: @Viki888 As per the example data given by the OP, deleting duplicates is perfectly fine. Both rows for 'john' have the same department ID.

Comment: Why do you need the DEPARTMENT table for this? The way you asked the question, you don't need it; but perhaps there is more to your question than what you put in your post. Then: How do you define "duplicate"? You have no duplicates in your EMPLOYEE table, because they are distinct by the ID column. Do you mean, "other than the ID column"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
delete  from Employee
where   id not in
        (
        select  minid
        from    (
                select  min(id) as minid
                from    Employee
                group by
                        name
                ,       salary
                ,       dep_ID
                ) sub
        )
```

[Example at rextester.com.](http://rextester.com/UHR69627)

Comment: @UsamaHaleem Please define "not working". This query solves the problem *as you've stated it*.

Comment: Perhaps in MySQL you need another subquery?  Edited in answer

Comment: @UsamaHaleem If this answer solved your problem, please mark it as accepted (using the "check" button next to it).

Answer (score 1):

for SQL..

Add a UNIQUE index on dep_ID column. When you write the ALTER statement, include the IGNORE keyword :

ALTER IGNORE TABLE employee
ADD UNIQUE INDEX idx_name (dep_ID);

This will delete all duplicate rows and future duplicate inserts will be avoided.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind using multiple statements and a temporary table, this solution works with any dbms:

```
create table tmp as
select min(ID), name, salary, dep_ID
from employee
group by name, salary, dep_ID;

truncate table employee;

insert into employee
select * from tmp;

drop table tmp;
```

Comment: The ID column doesn't contain duplicates

Comment: @Andomar That's why I group ID with a min()

Comment: Oops, you're right, I'm even using the same query :)

Comment: suppose if we are having more than 40 column then we have to mention all the columns in group by statement or is there any efficient way of doing this without mentioning all the columns ? because a large database could have more columns

Comment: I'm afraid you'd have to mention all the columns both in the group by and in the select clause.